# Using wildcards in column value in LIKE condition

Tags: jpa, wildcard, sql-like

I have a situation where I need to find an entity matching a given filename. The filename is in this form:

```
filename1 = "ABCD_126518.pdf";
filename2 = "XYZ_32162.pdf";
```

In the Oracle DB, I have entities with filename_patterns like the following:

```
ID | filename_pattern
1  | ABCD_
2  | KLM
3  | XYZ_
```

I need to find the pattern ID that the given filename matches to. In the given example it should be ID = 1 for filename1 and ID = 3 for filename2. How should the query look like in Java for the named query?

I need something like

```
SELECT p FROM FilenamePattern p WHERE p.filename_pattern || "%" LIKE :param;
```

We use Oracle DB and JPA 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
SELECT p FROM FilenamePattern p WHERE :param LIKE CONCAT(p.filename_pattern, "%")
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly does not work for me. Eclipse keeps saying: "The identification variable 'CONCAT' is not defined in the FORM clause." I also tried it in the reverse order (CONCAT() LIKE :param) but no result retrieved.